# Postfix is not retrying to send deferred emails

Tags: postfix

I have a Postfix server running and have the problem that send emails which are being deferred are not retried at all. They are present in the queue but never processed. If I do process the queue manually (via pfqueue or postqueue -f) the emails are delivered properly.

The output from the mail.log during that time looks like this:

```
Oct  6 12:19:37 example postfix/pickup[19048]: 8031D405F5: uid=1000 from=<no-reply@example.de>
Oct  6 12:19:37 example postfix/cleanup[19049]: 8031D405F5: message-id=<59d758b97cdb2_f514fc1f34405d1@example.de.mail>
Oct  6 12:19:37 example opendkim[1433]: 8031D405F5: DKIM-Signature field added (s=mail, d=example.de)
Oct  6 12:19:37 example postfix/qmgr[1565]: 8031D405F5: from=<no-reply@example.de>, size=984, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Oct  6 12:19:38 example postfix/smtp[19051]: 8031D405F5: to=<name@receiver.com>, relay=mx.xxx.net[xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]:25, delay=1.2, delays=0.05/0.01/0.41/0.7, dsn=4.7.1, status=deferred (host mx.xxx.net[xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] said: 451 4.7.1 Greylisted - try again in 300 seconds (in reply to RCPT TO command))
```

I have the following config running (output from postconf -n):

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
bounce_queue_lifetime = 2h
inet_interfaces = loopback-only
inet_protocols = ipv4
mailbox_size_limit = 0
maximal_backoff_time = 15m
maximal_queue_lifetime = 2h
milter_default_action = accept
milter_protocol = 2
minimal_backoff_time = 5m
mydestination = example.com, localhost.example.com
myhostname = example.com
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
myorigin = /etc/mailname
non_smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:12301
queue_run_delay = 5m
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
relayhost =
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:12301
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/fullchain.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/privkey.pem
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtpd_use_tls = yes
```

How can I make Postfix retry the queue automatically?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Postfix log was the following information:

```
Oct  6 13:57:51 xxx postfix[47965]: Postfix is running with backwards-compatible default settings
Oct  6 13:57:51 xxx postfix[47965]: See http://www.postfix.org/COMPATIBILITY_README.html for details
Oct  6 13:57:51 xxx postfix[47965]: To disable backwards compatibility use "postconf compatibility_level=2" and "postfix reload"
```

I never thought much of it, but I decided to add the `compatibility_level=2` to my config file. Since then the queue manager is working normally.

Since this was the only change I made, I'm quite certain that this was the cause for the problems. Postfix and the server were restarted several times before that, so a simple powercycle was not the reason.

Perhaps this is of help to someone.

Answer (score 4):

Greylisting at the destination mail server might prevent the e-mails from being delivered timely (your maximal_queue_lifetime is set to 2h). I'd revert following values back to sane defaults, and tweak from there.

From: http://www.postfix.org/TUNING_README.html

`queue_run_delay=300s` *(default: 300 seconds; before Postfix 2.4: 1000s)* -
*How often the queue manager scans the queue for deferred mail.*

`minimal_backoff_time=300s`
*(default: 300 seconds; before Postfix 2.4: 1000s)* -
*The minimal amount of time a message won't be looked at, and the minimal amount of time to stay away from a "dead" destination.*

`maximal_backoff_time=4000s`
*(default: 4000 seconds)* -
*The maximal amount of time a message won't be looked at after a delivery failure.*

`maximal_queue_lifetime=5d`
*(default: 5 days)* -
*How long a message stays in the queue before it is sent back as undeliverable. Specify 0 for mail that should be returned immediately after the first unsuccessful delivery attempt.*

`bounce_queue_lifetime=5d`
*(default: 5 days, available with Postfix version 2.1 and later)* -
*How long a MAILER-DAEMON message stays in the queue before it is considered undeliverable. Specify 0 for mail that should be tried only once.*

I hope this helps.

Comment: I started out with the default parameters. The queue was not processed as well, so I don't think it's related.

Comment: But William is correct. Your current configuration will cause permanent failure even if your server or the receiving MTA is down / disconnected / unreachable for two hours.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, I will increase the time. However I don't see how this is related to the current problem I experience. The deferred mail from my example is not retried at all. Even with the current settings there should be attempts for resending it.